# Dual spaces in Dirac's notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, notation

If I have a certain operator $A$ as well as the following stationary state $|\psi _0\rangle$, and I know that $A|\psi_0\rangle =0$, can I say that $\langle \psi _0|A^\dagger$ also equals zero?

Comment: LaTeX tips: Use \langle and \rangle for Dirac notation, and rather than a plus, you can use a superscript \dagger for the adjoint. (See edit.)

Answer (score 1):

$A |\psi_0\rangle = 0$ if and only if, for an arbitrary state $|\phi\rangle$,
$$
\langle \phi | A |\psi_0\rangle = 0.
$$
By taking the complex conjugate of this equation we have that 
$$
\langle \psi_0 | A^\dagger |\phi\rangle = 0
$$
for an arbitrary $|\phi\rangle$, and so 
$$
\langle \psi_0 | A^\dagger = 0.
$$